# Angular bind-html + $sce still remove the inline style

Tags: html, angularjs

I write simple custom filter that return string value.

The value contain html string and inline style

When binding angular remove the styles

Here is my filter

```
siteApp.filter('specialText', ['$filter', '$sce', function ($filter, $sce) {
    return function (code, items, defaults) {
          var out = defaults;
          if (items && items.length) {
            var arr = $filter('filter')(items, { code: code }, true);
            if (arr && arr.length > 0) {
                out = arr[0].value;
                $sce.trustAsHtml(out);
            }
        }
        return out;
    };
}]);
```

And This is my html

```
 <div  ng-bind-html="'body_message' | specialText : specific_texts :''"></div>
```

The original text contain inline style but angular remove inline style on binding

[image]

How can I keep the inline styles

FULL EXAMPLE CODE

```html
<body >
    <div ng-app="siteApp">
        <div ng-controller="ctrl">
            {{'test1' | specialText : arr :'missing....' }}
            <div ng-bind-html="'test1' | specialText : arr :'missing....'"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-sanitize/1.5.6/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script>
        var siteApp = angular.module('siteApp', ['ngSanitize']);
        siteApp.filter('specialText', ['$filter', '$sce', function ($filter, $sce) {
            return function (code, items, defaults) {
                var out = defaults;
                if (items && items.length) {
                    var arr = $filter('filter')(items, { code: code }, true);
                    if (arr && arr.length > 0) {
                        out = arr[0].value;                      
                        $sce.trustAsHtml(out);
                    }
                }
                return out;
            };
        }]);
        siteApp.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.arr = [{ "code": "test1", "rte": true, "value": "<p style=\"text-align: left;\">First Row</p>\n<h1 style=\"text-align: center;\">Second Center Row</h1>" }];
        }]);
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I have used the same and the styles were not removed. Can you try once binding it from scope variable instead of filter?

Comment: I add snippet with full code

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the output of `$sce.trustAsHtml(out)`. Inside your if statement try `out = $sce.trustAsHtml(out);` and it should be ok.